# is it possible to create a list of lists on a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

My goal is to build all possible combinations between the keys in a dictionary (plus a few other rules that don't really matter), so I wrote the recursive function bellow.

```
dict = {3: 54, 37: 100, 56: 33}

def dosomething(dict, indent, stop, position):
    if dict == {} or stop <0:
        return

    keys = dict.keys()
    for k in keys:
        if k > position:
            print indent, k
            dosomething(dict, indent + "    ", stop -1, k)

indent = " "
dosomething(dict, indent, 4, 0)
```

Printing the result show the values I want:

```
 56
 3
     56
     37
         56
 37
     56
```

but now I'd like to have them in a list of lists where the elements would be:

```
[56]
[3,56]
[3,37,56]
[37,56]
```

Would anyone be able to help me with that?

Comment: I think you should check your indentation and I am not the one of the downvoters

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What? Why don't you just use `itertools`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: hi Vignesh, the indentation is merely to see the output better;  mkrieger, I'm trying to combine all keys on a dictionary, but I'd like each of the combinations to be an element of a list.

Comment: And why shouldn't, for example, `[3]` and `[37]` be part of the result?

Comment: Why is there no element `[37]` or `[3, 37]`?

Comment: "all possible combinations" sounds like `powerset` from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for me.

Comment: I wasn't really caring about the missing elements, just wondering if it could be achieved using recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will generate a list of all possible combinations of keys

```
import itertools

dict = {3: 54, 37: 100, 56: 33}

combos = []

for i in range(len(dict.keys())):

    combos.extend([sorted(l) for l in itertools.combinations(dict.keys(), i+1)])

print combos
```

Will return:

```
[[56], [3], [37], [56, 3], [56, 37], [3, 37], [56, 3, 37]]
```

Comment: `[j for j in l]` ? Why not `list(l)` ?

Comment: and since you added `sorted`, you don't even need `list` now.

Comment: thanks for your reply